# missing authentification token for REST request elastic search

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

It's the first time I'm posting a question here: I'm creating a website in AngularJS for the front end and NodeJS for the back end. This website is supposed to give me information about my elastic search clusters, get some information from `Elasticsearch` index. I have tried to use `Elasticsearch Javascript API` to do my request but it doesn't work.

I'm using `ElasticSearch` 5.4

Here's an example of request :

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client ({

    host: 'https://noev02pe.fr:9200',
    auth: 'user:password',
    log: 'trace',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic user:password',
     }
});

export function connect() {
  client.search({
    index: 'metric-prod*',
    q: 'kafka'
  }
, function (error, response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

and the response on the console is :

```
{ error:
    { root_cause: [ [Object] ],
      type: 'security_exception',
      reason: 'missing authentication token for REST request [/metric-
      prod*/_search?q=kafka]',
      header: { 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic realm="security" charset="UTF-8"' 
    } },
  status: 401 }
```

I also tried doing classic post request :

```
   export function createUser(request,response,next){
      var username = request.params.username;
      var userData = querystring.stringify(request.body);
      console.log(userData);
      var options ={
       hostname: 'noev02vr.fr',
       port: 9200,
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        path: "_xpack/security/user/"+username,
    method:'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + prodPass,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Content-Length': userData.length
    }
  };



 var post_req=http.request(options, function(res){
            console.log('post user reussi');
            res.on('data', function(data){

             response.writeHead(res.statusCode);
             response.write(data);
             console.log(res.statusCode);
           });

         });

          post_req.write(userData);
          post_req.end();

       }
```

and I get a 500 error.

Comment: wild speculation: did you forget to base64 encode username and password maybe, when sending the authorization header? Also the official docs use a different mechanism to configure user/pass so that this base64 encoding happens automatically. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/auth-reference.html#auth-reference

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me! I tried with both but in the Javascript API you don't need to encode, you can use directly user:password . It's for the classic http request that you need to encode , that's my variable prodPass : the password encoded in base64

Comment: Any update on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Basic Authentication

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({
  node: 'https://localhost:9200', //Replace with your URL.
  auth: { 
    username: 'elastic',
    password: '*****' //Replace with your password
  }
})
```

Otherwise, you can provide your credentials in the node(s) URL

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({
  node: 'https://username:password@localhost:9200'
})
```

If you have enable ssl then this are the config

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const client = new Client({
  node: 'https://localhost:9200',
  auth: {
    username: 'elastic',
    password: '*****'
  },
  ssl: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./cacert.pem'),
    rejectUnauthorized: false
  }
})
```

You can get Your username and password refer this link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-enterprise/current/ece-password-reset-elastic.html